# I want my table to connect on the top (css / html)

Tags: html, css

So I have a 2x2 table which will be the whole layout of my website. I want the two top cells to connect into one so I have made the border on left (for the right cell) and on right (for the left side) to be 0, however there is still some space between the two cell, so they do not connect.

Keep in mind that I want the two bottom cells to have space between then!

css of top right cell:

```
.one {
  width: 25%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 0px;
}
```

css of top left cell:

```
.two {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 0px;
}
```

image:

[PREVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAAFm.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.one {
  width: 25%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.ghost {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  left: 10px;
  top: -15%;
}
.two {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 0px;
}
.three {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.four {
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row-1">
    <td class="one">cell 1<div class="ghost"></div></td>
    <td class="two">cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="three">cell 3</td>
    <td class="four">cell 4</td> 
</table>
```

Here's a hack, but I'm sure there's a better way than this. Basically this just adds another element with equal height and only top and bottom borders, and then positions it between the two cells on top. Again, it's a total hack and I would recommend waiting for a better answer, but if you don't get one I guess this can be a fallback. Also, if you use this, it's very important that the parent (.one) has `position: relative` because the .ghost is going to look for a parent with a non-static position to reference. Hope you get a better answer than this though.

Comment: It doesnt work exactly like that for my table. I get the idea and thanks for your help but in my website the two horizontal borders aren't located where they should be, might try to figure out something similar myself.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Thanks Adam! It does the job, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem. I don't use tables a lot in html so I didn't know it off the top of my head. I'm kind of embarrased about the previous hack I posted now that I know how easy of a fix it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think attribute `colspan` still supported in HTML5:

```css
/*This only to confirm whether each cell has padding/spacing */
.addBorder{
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table class="addBorder">
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" class="addBorder" align="center">Head</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="addBorder">content 1</td>
 <td class="addBorder">Content 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```